# Wordpress WYSIWYG image links broken

Tags: image, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

In a custom plugin I invoke a WYSIWYG editor like this:

```
<?php the_editor(get_option("reminder_text"), 'reminder_text'); ?>
```

Everything works fine, until I try to insert an image (uploader or external source, no difference).

Example: I enter the image path and the image is displayed correctly. When i save the form and return to it, the image is displayed as broken and the path is surrounded by escaped quotes, e. g.:

```
\"http://www.my-image-link-here.jpg\"
```

Has someone an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the data is sanitized when inserted in the database, you need to clean up the returning results of `get_option`.

Take a look at the documentation about [**Data Validation**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

Use:

```
the_editor( esc_attr( get_option( "reminder_text" ) ), 'reminder_text' );
```

*[Related answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82405/12615) at WordPress StackExchange.*